# Can the writematrix command in matlab specify the number of decimal places?

Tags: matlab, file, matrix

The *writematrix* command can write matrices to text files. For example, for a matrix like the following

```matlab
A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

It can be written to file `a.txt` using the *writematrix* command

```matlab
A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
writematrix(A, 'a.txt', 'WriteMode', 'append', 'Delimiter', ' ');
```

The output is

```matlab
1 2 3 4
```

But if I want the output like below

```matlab
1.0000 2.0000 3.0000 4.0000
```

How do I go about using *writematrix*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert `A` into a character array with [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) in the required format before using [`writematrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) i.e.

```
writematrix(num2str(A,'%.4f '), 'a.txt', 'WriteMode', 'append', 'Delimiter', 'tab');
```

Comment: The output is `"1.0000 2.0000 3.0000 4.0000"`, not `1.0000 2.0000 3.0000 4.0000`.

Comment: @Lancdorr Please verify that you have copied/pasted it correctly. Notice the delimiter flag as tab at the end

Comment: When there are negative numbers in `A`, there are no spaces in some places in the output.

Comment: @Lancdorr   I have tried with mixed data of positive and negative integers but your issue could not be reproduced. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Sorry, maybe there is something wrong with my program. But I want to ask you one more question, When there are negative numbers in the array, there may be two spaces in some places in the output. How to program if each number is required to be separated by only one space?

Comment: @Lancdorr With only one space, the matrix will be unreadable in the text file if there are numbers with different orders of 10 (particularly if it is a large matrix). Anyway, It would be better to use `fprintf` instead of `writematrix` for requirements like these. This added requirement is not relevant to the original question asked in your post above though.

Answer (score 1):

Converting into a character array did not work for me. Use this piece of code:

```
writematrix(round(A, 4), 'a.txt', 'WriteMode', 'append', 'Delimiter', ' ');
```